# SetCurrentItem() in ViewPager not smooth in the first scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, smooth-scrolling

This problem is happening to me for ages. When I have a ViewPager and I try to scroll it programmatically with `setCurrentItem(<index>, true)` the first scroll is not smooth a all. After this first scroll is working at it should.

Anyone know how to make it smooth from the first scroll??

Cheers!

Comment: Does it happen on every device? This is probably a graphics issue on your device.

Comment: It happens in physical device and virtual device in a fresh start of the app.